# Isometry maps closed unit ball to closed unit balI

Tags: real-analysis, isometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces.

We say that a linear operator $T:X\to Y$ an isometry if for every $x\in X,$ we have 
$$\|Tx\| = \|x\|.$$

> **Question:** Let the closed unit ball of $X$ be 
>   $$B_X=\{x\in X: \|x\|\leq 1 \}.$$
>   Is it true that an isometry maps closed unit ball **onto** closed unit ball, that is, 
>   $$T(B_X) = B_Y?$$

I think it is true, as isometry preserves distance. 
So I proceed to prove the equality.

Clearly every isometry is an injection. Therefore, 
$$T(B_X)\subseteq B_Y.$$

However, I have trouble proving 
$$B_Y\subseteq T(B_X).$$
Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, consider an isometric embedding of finite dimensional spaces with different dimension.